# Elasticsearch driver: ES ODBC DSN configuration: connection failed

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to configure Elasticsearch ODBC DSN I get this error:
[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afr9i.png)

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? As a wild guess, Windows might not like the TLS 1.2, this link might be helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi

Comment: thanx for the answer, I'm using windows 7

Comment: May I ask you did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: No not yet Ihave consulted the link but as a beginner I didn't undersand many things but now i have another issue which is: connection failed: [elastic][EsODBC 7.6.2(v7.6.1-4....)Driver] Couldn't connect to server (code:7; Failed to connect to localhost posrt 9200: Concection refused)